# From Completable to Observable

Tags: android, asynchronous, rx-java2

I will try to be more clear I can.

I want to loop the elements inside a list, for each element in the MAIN_LIST, start an elaboration. The elaboration consists in another list, SECOND_LIST, that has to be looped. When all the elaboration on each item of the SECOND_LIST is finished, start do the same with the next element in the MAIN_LIST.

When finish elaborating all elements in the MAIN_LIST return complete.

Here is I try to achieve this, but I think there is a better way.

Thanks for your help!

Method that loop the MAIN_LIST

```
    public Completable checkGroupExpiration(List<CheckVersion.ServiceStatus> serviceStatusList) {
    return Completable.create(emitter -> {
        Observable.fromIterable(serviceStatusList)
                .concatMapCompletable(serviceStatus -> {
                    return checkGroupExpiration(serviceStatus.service, serviceStatus.lastUpdate);
                }).subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                if (!emitter.isDisposed())
                    emitter.onComplete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                if (!emitter.isDisposed())
                    emitter.onComplete();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Method that loop SECOND_LIST

```
    protected Completable checkGroupExpiration(String group, long ttl) {
    return Completable.create(emitter -> {
        readFile(MASTER_NOTE)
                .map(s -> {
                    return new Gson().fromJson(s, MasterNote.class);
                }).flatMapObservable(masterNote -> {
            return Observable.fromIterable(masterNote.savedFiles.entrySet());
        }).filter(stringCacheInfoEntry -> {
            return stringCacheInfoEntry.getValue().group.equals(group) && stringCacheInfoEntry.getValue().ttl < ttl;
        }).concatMapCompletable(stringCacheInfoEntry -> {
            return getFile(stringCacheInfoEntry.getKey(), false)
                    .doOnSuccess(file -> {
                        String fileName = file.getName();
                        file.delete();
                        Log.d(TAG, "File deleted => " + fileName + " from group => " + group);
                    }).ignoreElement();
        }).subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                if (!emitter.isDisposed())
                    emitter.onComplete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                if (!emitter.isDisposed())
                    emitter.onComplete();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Don't subscribe to an inner flow inside `create` but use the flows directly:

```java
public Completable checkGroupExpiration(
        List<CheckVersion.ServiceStatus> serviceStatusList) {
    retrn Observable.fromIterable(serviceStatusList)
            .concatMapCompletable(serviceStatus -> 
                checkGroupExpiration(serviceStatus.service, serviceStatus.lastUpdate)
            )
            .ignoreElements();
}

protected Completable checkGroupExpiration(String group, long ttl) {
    return 
         readFile(MASTER_NOTE)
         .map(s ->
                new Gson().fromJson(s, MasterNote.class)
         )
         .flatMapObservable(masterNote ->
              Observable.fromIterable(masterNote.savedFiles.entrySet())
         )
         .filter(stringCacheInfoEntry ->
              stringCacheInfoEntry.getValue().group.equals(group) 
              && stringCacheInfoEntry.getValue().ttl < ttl
         )
         .concatMapCompletable(stringCacheInfoEntry -> 
              getFile(stringCacheInfoEntry.getKey(), false)
              .doOnSuccess(file -> {
                    String fileName = file.getName();
                    file.delete();
                    Log.d(TAG, "File deleted => " + fileName + " from group => " + group);
              })
              .ignoreElement()
        );
}
```

Comment: And what if I want to loop the main_list start all the loop of the second_list asynchronously and wait for all to complete?